# Is it possible to render a JSX component (be it a table or span) inside an inline If-Else in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently trying to render a JSX table inside an inline If-Else condition, where it would receive data from an const, confirming that the API is loaded. And by being loaded, it would show the table or span with all the data. Below, the code:

```
<div>
...

  <span className = {apiloaded === true ? 'show_info' : 'dontshow_info'}>
     <h4>
     Tracking data: 
     </h4>
  </span>

  {apiloaded === true ? end.events.forEach(item => { 
   {console.log(apiloaded)}
                            
   <span> {item.data} </span>

  }) : error }

</div>
```

The api is being correctly called, since the console log displays `showtd` 6 times, being it the correct number of arrays on the specific call made.

But the table refuses to load. Is it even possible to render the table inside this condition, or the problem would be the `forEach`?

**SOLUTION BELOW.**

Comment: The function you are passing to `forEach` doesn't return anything. That's probably why you don't see anything.

Comment: `{showtd === true ? end.eventos.map(item => { 
   {console.log(showtd)}
                            
  return (<span> {item.data} </span>);

  }) : error }
`
As @FelixKling figured out, This code will work.

Comment: I've edited and tried to clarify my code a bit. This function (apiloaded) returns true on other instances above this snippet. Why wouldn't it do so on that part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. You need to change `.forEach` to `.map` and `return` the new value.

```
 {
    showtd ? end.eventos.map((item) => {
          {
            console.log(showtd);
          }
          return <span> {item.data} </span>;
        })
      : error;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The conditional operator is not the problem here.

---

There are languages where you can dip in and out of "programming" and "writing". PHP is a typical example:

```
<p>This gets written to the output</p>
<?php 
    # This is some code
?>
```

JSX is **not** one of them.

---

Your render function needs to return content to render.

```
return <p>Hello</p>
```

You can put JavaScript expressions inside JSX, and *what the expression evaluates to* gets inserted into the output:

```
return <p>{"Hello"}</p>
```

or

```
const data = "Hello";
return <p>{data}</p>
```

or

```
const generateData = () => {
    return "Hello";
};
return <p>{generateData()}</p>
```

---

A `forEach` call **doesn't return anything**.

If you want to insert every element in an array with some transformation, then use a `map` call instead.

That will output a new array with the changed values.

```
const data = ["foo", "bar"];
return <p>{data.map( element => <span>{element}</span> )}</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const App = () => {
    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        // get api response 
        setTableData(data);
        
    }, [])

    return(
        <>
            {tableData.length > 0 ?
                <table>
                    <tr><th>.....</th></tr>
                    // Loop
                    {tableData.map((data,i) => (
                        <tr key={i}>
                            <td>{data.yourkeyName}</td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </table>
            :
                <p>No records found</p>
            }
        </>
    );
}
```